# Securely connect to mysql Server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Im currently creating a login form part of my third year final project that connects to a mysql database. I previously have been connecting to the database using a connection string that was hard coded into the application.

However, because this application is meant to be ready for opensource use I don't want the username and password to be hard coded into the database.

I've done a decent amount of research on this and came to 2 conclusions:

1. Add connections string to the settings.settings file and encrypt it. (BAD, either will use RSA machine specific key or will use hand written encryption (hand written encryption key. Also Bad)
2. Create a php script where the client sends a query to the script and the script returns the results.

I was wondering if there where any other methods of securely connecting to a MySql Server. Keep in mind this is going to be open source and distributed to alot of machine so having Trusted_user = true. Is not an option.

Comment: Please define what you mean by secure. Read only access?

Comment: Every key is only as secure as the place you store it in. Sooner or later you will have to write something in clear, unencrypted text to use it.

Comment: @IanNewson I don't want the username and password to be in plane text

Comment: With the PHP script you have to assume it will be found and called by someone who is not supposed to be using it.  With the C# app you also need to assume it could be used with a stolen laptop or any PC left unattended at work.

Comment: @Christopher I understand, that is why method one doesn't seem like a good option. Writing my own method would only be one more step a hacker would have to do to gain access to my server.

Comment: Why not? What problems do you envisage occurring if people had access to the username and password?

Comment: Do you not want them to be able to connect directly to the database with another client perhaps?

Comment: @IanNewson Actually good point, currently my sql user has * permisison. but I could make it so they can only read and write!

Comment: If a hacker has root access to the server your software is running on, it is already Game Over. The onus is on the operator of the server to secure it so that this doesn't happen. There's nothing more to it.